# Mean of quasi-geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How can I obtain a closed form for the mean of the following discreet distribution?

$$
 \Pr(X=k) =
  \begin{cases} 
      p\,(1 - p)^k & \text{, if $k < n$} \\
      p\,(1 - p)^n\,(1 - q)^{(k-n)}&, \text{ if $k \ge n$} \\
  \end{cases},
$$

where $p$, $q$ and $n$ are parameters of the discreet distribution. Note that, if $p=q$ or $n = 0$ or $n\rightarrow\infty$, then the distribution becomes the geometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a computational exercise.

Let $$G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^kp(1-p)^k+\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^kp(1-p)^n(1-q)^{k-n}$$
be the [probability generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).

Both parts are computable in closed form using [geometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series) [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and then you can differentiate it to get the mean.